# How do you redirect context roots in WebSphere 7?

Tags: websphere, websphere-7

How do you map 2 context roots to one application in WebSphere 6.

For example,  I have an application with a context root of "/", which is obviously the default application.  I want requests directed at context root "/sample" to be redirected to the "/" path.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must do that on the http server's configuration side instead WebSphere's side. Are you using a front http server?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, Thanks.

I added this to the config file of the HTTP server

```
ProxyPass  /sample/  /
```